# PLSQL same data with different dates from same table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, union-all

I have a table in Oracle and I want to get difference of sums of debit and credit columns for sysdate and the same difference of sums of debit and credit columns from 6 months ago

My query is

```
select a.name,a.id, nvl(sum(a.debit),0)-nvl(sum(a.credit),0) current_bal
from mytable a
where a.id='1092' and a.docdate<=sysdate
group by a.name,a.id
union
select b.name,b.id,nvl(sum(b.debit),0)-nvl(sum(b.credit),0) current_bal1
from mytable b
where b. id='1092' and b.docdate<=add_months(sysdate,-6)
group by b.name,b.id;
```

I am getting the correct result but the query is returning two rows, where as my need is to show this result as a single row.

Any suggestions / correction in my query please.

Comment: In a single row - do you want to show them in comma separated manner?

Comment: No, I am getting two rows like first row: id-1   name-1   120000 and second row        id-1   name-1   250000, I want them in a single row like id-1 name-1 120000 250000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select a.name,a.id, nvl(sum(CASE WHEN a.docdate<=sysdate THEN a.debit END),0)-nvl(sum(CASE WHEN a.docdate<=sysdate THEN a.credit END),0) current_bal,
nvl(sum(CASE WHEN b.docdate<=add_months(sysdate,-6) THEN a.debit END),0)-nvl(sum(CASE WHEN b.docdate<=add_months(sysdate,-6) THEN a.credit END),0) current_bal1
from mytable a
where a.id='1092'
group by a.name,a.id;
```

**-- Update**

If you are facing any issue then easiest way for you is to use the self join between sub-queries as follows:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.ID, A.CURRENT_BAL, B.CURRENT_BAL1
FROM
(select a.name,a.id, nvl(sum(a.debit),0)-nvl(sum(a.credit),0) current_bal
from mytable a
where a.id='1092' and a.docdate<=sysdate
group by a.name,a.id) A
JOIN 
(select b.name,b.id,nvl(sum(b.debit),0)-nvl(sum(b.credit),0) current_bal1
from mytable b
where b. id='1092' and b.docdate<=add_months(sysdate,-6)
group by b.name,b.id) B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.NAME = B.NAME;
```

Comment: its returning a single row but empty columns

Comment: Which columns are empty? last two?

Comment: all result colums, i mean empty result, no data

Comment: Actually my query is correct but I am getting two rows like first row: id-1 name-1 120000 and second row id-1 name-1 250000, I want them in a single row like id-1 name-1 120000 250000

Comment: It has worked Tejash. Good work. Thanks. The update section solved my issue. It means I needed a join query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select a.name, a.id, 
       coalesce(sum(a.debit), 0) - coalesce(sum(a.credit), 0) as current_bal,
       (sum(case when a.docdate < add_months(sysdate, -6) then a.debit else 0 end) -
        sum(case when a.docdate < add_months(sysdate, -6) then a.credit else 0 end)
       ) as bal_6_months
from mytable a
where a.id = '1092' and a.docdate <= sysdate
group by a.name, a.id;
```

This puts the two values in the same row.  That seems more useful to me then having them in different rows.

Comment: its returning a single row but empty columns

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
select a.name,a.id, LISTAGG(nvl(sum(a.debit),0)-nvl(sum(a.credit),0), ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.id) current_bal
from mytable a
where a.id='1092' and a.docdate<=sysdate
group by a.name,a.id
union
select b.name,b.id, LISTAGG(nvl(sum(a.debit),0)-nvl(sum(a.credit),0), ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.id) current_bal
from mytable b
where b. id='1092' and b.docdate<=add_months(sysdate,-6)
group by b.name,b.id;
```